HR letter with the purpose of attending an onsite interview at another company
Another company has offered to interview me onsite at one of their premises in Europe. However, I am currently employed at my company, and I need an HR letter from my manager that includes "the purpose of travel, outlining the specific work-related or business-related reason for visiting the Schengen area."
How do I go about doing this? Do I need to state the purpose of my visit in the HR letter, or could I just mention the purpose of my visit in my cover letter and omit it from the HR letter?
I am going there on a business visa since tourist visas take so long and there are no near appointments for it.

Are you talking about a letter that you supply when you apply for a visa, or about some letter that is internal to your current company?

Who is paying for your travel?

If you apply for a visa for business purposes, you are expected to go there on behalf of your employer, being paid by your employer, and with your expenses covered by your employer.
An alternative could be if your prospective employer invited you and covered your expenses for the whole trip.
If neither is true, it can hardly be handled as a visa for business purposes, as you will need to provide stronger evidence of your personal circumstances, including your ability to pay for the trip (which is set aside for business visas as a company is doing it), and it may be especially difficult to show ties to your home country when you are actually in the first steps of trying to move to a Schengen Area country.
As the ultimate purpose of your travel (beyond this quick visit for an interview) is a long term stay (I suppose), you may find better advice on Expatriates.SE.
See also related questions and answers:

Schengen visa category required for job interview
Schengen Visa for Job Interview, Minimum balance in Account

Note that in both cases the trio was paid by the prospective employer.
